# String concatenation in inherited class

Tags: java, string

I have a class called `A` and there's a String declared in it. And i have 2 other classes `B and C` which is inherited from `A`

```
public abstract class A {
    protected String ss="";

    public abstract String someMethod();
}

public class B extends A{
    public String someMethod(){
        int i=8;
        return ss+="$"+i;
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    public String someMethod() {
        int i=9;
       return ss+="$"+i;
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
A aa = new B();
aa.someMethod();

A aaa = new C();    
aaa.someMethod();
```

When I print `aaa.someMethod();` - why haven't the strings from class B and C been appended? I want them to be appended. How can I do this ?

Comment: Please post [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Please post real code. in java doesn't have `inherit` keyword

Comment: Your `aa.someMethod();` returns a string, rather than printing. You need to move the invocation in a `System.out.println(aa.someMethod())`, to see the output.

Comment: I did, but it only gives the result of the Class C's method, and hasn't got appended

Comment: @sharonHwk.. What do you want it to append? Please post expected output. And also, always post the real code here, else we keep on removing your compiler error, and then you say, it's a typo.

Comment: Please format your code better when asking for help on a professional site. It makes it much easier to analyze your issue. Also, you should post working, compilable code samples. I recommend reading up on [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Examples](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac A.java B.java C.java Test.java**

**/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java Test**

```
$8
$9
```

nothing surprising here, B method someMethod() calls B method, C method someMethod() calls C method...

file A.java:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected String ss="";
    public abstract String someMethod();
}
```

file B.java

```
public class B extends A
{
    public String someMethod()
    {
        int i=8;
        return ss+="$"+i;
    }
}
```

file C.java

```
public class C extends A
{
    public String someMethod()
    {
        int i=9;
        return ss+="$"+i;
    }
}
```

file Test.java

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String pArgs[])
    {
        A aa = new B();
        System.out.println(aa.someMethod());
        A aaa = new C();
        System.out.println(aaa.someMethod());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Overridden methods in Java do ***not*** automatically invoke their superclass parents. So, in your `C` subclass, calling `someMethod` does not invoke the method from its parent `A`, unless you *explicitly* call super.

```
public class C extends A
    public String someMethod(){
        int i=9;
        return ss+= super.someMethod()+"$"+i;
    }
}
```

I assume you are doing this to learn, because otherwise this is a pretty terrible way to manage your inherited classes and their properties.

Comment: But the parent of `C` is class `A` in OP code. Did you misread that?

Comment: And now you are calling an abstract method. Note that, calling super class method is not the issue here. OP is not printing the result returned by `someMethod()`, so it does not do anything. So, he might be thinking that it is printing the empty string declared in class A, and not appending the value `"$" + i`, from class C and B. Funny question this is.

Comment: Actually, I am guessing that the OP is wondering why the strings from the separate `B` and `C` instances aren't appended. But barring an update from him I am answering the most 'sensible' question.